# iPhone - parsing a plist file into an array without success

Tags: iphone, null, nsarray, plist, fill

I try to put a plist file content into an array using this functions :

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DataFile" ofType:@"plist"];
self.contentData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

But self.contentData keeps being null...
I don't understand why. I used the same code than the one shown in the Apple "PageControl" sample project ([See here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html)), using also a pList file with the same structure (list of Dictionary items with 2 strings inside).

path is filled with : /var/Mobile/Applications/somehexvalues/MyApp.app/DataFile.plist

How could I know what is going wrong ?

NSLog(@"%@", [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path]); gives :

```
"Item 0" =     {
    imageKey = "hearts.png";
    nameKey = Hearts;
};
"Item 1" =     {
    imageKey = "leef.png";
    nameKey = Leef;
};
"Item 2" =     {
    imageKey = "round.png";
    nameKey = Round;
};
```

Comment: I know you are sure that the plist is an array, but just to make me happy please add `NSLog(@"%@", [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path]);`

Comment: Did you include this plist in your project's resources?

Comment: @fluchtpunkt : of course, the plist is in the project :-) The NSLog gives ... see EDIT...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PLIST has an NSDitionary instead of an NSArray, that is why you get null. If you try to load an NSArray into a NSDcitionary, you will get null as well.

Comment: so how do you explain that this works with the Apple sample code ? Did you look at it ?

Comment: You're right. In fact, in the Apple sample code, the main container is an array. But when you create a plist from xcode and add a row, the main container is a dictionnary. You need to edit manually the plist to have an array as main container. Do you know a way to have an array as main container when building a plist from xcode without having to edit the source code ?